# Read href inside anchor tag using Java

Tags: java, regex

I have an HTML snippet like this :

```
<a href="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" target="_blank" class="view_job_link">View or apply to job</a>
```

I want to read href value XXXXXXXXXX using Java.

Point to note: I am reading the HTML file from a URL using inputstreamreader(url.openStream()).

I am getting a complete HTML file, and above snippet is a part of that file.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Karunjay Anand

Comment: I notice you tagged your question 'regex'. Please read this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: I have a big string of html and need to extract the href="..." text...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670593/java-i-have-a-big-string-of-html-and-need-to-extract-the-href-text)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a html parser like [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). The API is easy to learn and for your case,the following code snippet will do

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com/");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3*1000);
Elements links = doc.select("a[href]"); // a with href
for (Element link : links) {
   System.out.println("Href = "+link.attr("abs:href"));
}
```

Comment: You can also use `link.absUrl("href")`.

Answer (score 1):

Use an HTML parser like [TagSoup](http://mercury.ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/) or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java's own [HtmlEditorKit](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html) for parsing html. This way you wont need to depend on any third party html parser. [Here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/HTMLEditorKitDemo.htm) is an example of how to use it.