# What would be the correct regular expression for extracting a href from a html line? (Java)

Tags: java, html, regex

Hi I am trying to extract text which a href defines in a html line. For example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
```

I want to get "style.css" or:

```
<a href="target0.html"><img align="center" src="thumbnails/image001.jpg" width="154" height="99">
```

I want to get "target0.html"

What would be the correct Java code to do this?

Comment: I think the answer on this question is what you are looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670593/java-i-have-a-big-string-of-html-and-need-to-extract-the-href-text

Comment: Mandatory SO link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348    Read the answer with the most upvotes ; )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public static String getHref(String str)
    {
        int startIndex = str.indexOf("href=");
        if (startIndex < 0)
            return "";
        return str.substring(startIndex + 6, str.indexOf("\"", startIndex + 6));
    }
```

This method assumes that the html is well formed and it only works for the first href in the string but I'm sure you can extrapolate from here.

Answer (score 1):

I realize you asked about using regular expressions, but [jsoup](http://jsoup.org) makes this so simple and is much less error prone:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import nu.xom.ParsingException;
import nu.xom.ValidityException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class HrefExtractor {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws SAXException, ValidityException, ParsingException, IOException {
        final Document document = Jsoup.parse("<a href=\"target0.html\"><img align=\"center\" src=\"thumbnails/image001.jpg\" width=\"154\" height=\"99\">");
        final Elements links = document.select("a[href]");
        for (final Element element : links) {
            System.out.println(element.attr("href"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not try the following but it should be something like this:

```
'Pattern.compile("<(?:link|a\s+)[^>]*href=\"(.*?)\"")'
```

But I'd recommend you to use one of available HTML or even XML parsers for this task.